# How do I use enum in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, enums

I am learning C language with Visual Studio 2012 and using old book(the book using turbo C).

The code below is not working with following error message.

```
void main()
{
    enum AA {QQ, WW, EE, RR, TT};
    enum BB a, b, c, d, e;
    a = QQ;
    b = WW;
    c = EE;
    d = EE;
    e = TT;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);
    a = RR + TT;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

result :
  0 1 2 3 4
  7

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'main::BB'
1>          Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-         style cast or function-style cast

When mouseover on equal(=) I can see 'a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "QQ" or "WW", etc.

How do I get the result?

Comment: But you haven't defined an enumeration named `BB`?

Comment: Also, you are making a C++ program, not a C program, as indicated by the error messages (they mention `static_cast` and "C-style cast", both of which are C++ specific). And talking about the error message, ***on which line*** do you get the error?

Comment: oh I'm really beginner of programming. I don't know 'define an enumeration' so my problem is using visual studio? I can see the errors from a = QQ to e = TT and a = RR + TT

Comment: set option `/TC` and change to `enum AA a, b, c, d, e;`, `d = RR;`

Comment: and c style cast E.g. `a = (enum AA)(RR + TT);`

Comment: Avoid the book, it may contain `turbo c` specific things. (For ex: void main, no headers etc)

Answer (score 1):

In main, on the first line you are declaring an enumerated type and calling it `AA`. On the second line you are trying to declare 5 variables of type `enum BB`, which you haven't defined yet.

This can't work. The code could make sense if the variables you declare were of type `enum AA`, the one you've just declared.

Change those `B`s into `A`s and you're fine.

*Furthermore,* in Visual Studio to have your code get compiled as a C code instead of a C++ code, simply just change your source file name from *blabla.cpp* to *blabla.c*.